# Electron application handle end task from task manager windows

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, event-handling, electron

I need an electron event handler that detects a force quit/end task from task manager in windows. I would like this event handler to be able to send an http request before ending the program. I am currently using:

```
   app.on('before-quit', function () {
       //send http request...
   })
```

to handle the force quit event. While this handler works with force quit in mac environment, it does not get fired in windows using the task manager.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but I think the `'will-quit'` event is worth a shot https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-will-quit

Comment: Every `xy-quit` event says "On Windows, this event will not be emitted if the app is closed due to a shutdown/restart of the system or a user logout." - I'm afraid you're out of luck with this :/

Comment: Tried the will-quit a while ago, but didn't work... That is unfortunate. Thanks for the help guys